# Filtering queryset by boolean field on parent class

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm not sure why this is causing me such a problem but I can't seem to get it figured out. I've got a CSV and PDF export for products in our Mezzanine / Cartridge product DB. It exports each ProductVariation in a row. Works great but I need to add a filter that exports only published products for instance. ProductVariations have a foreignkey relation to the Product model:

```
class ProductVariation(Priced):
"""
A combination of selected options from
``SHOP_OPTION_TYPE_CHOICES`` for a ``Product`` instance.
"""

product = models.ForeignKey("Product", related_name="variations")
```

The product model subclasses Displayable:

```
class Product(Displayable, Priced, RichText, AdminThumbMixin):
"""
Container model for a product that stores information common to
all of its variations such as the product's title and description.
"""
```

The Displayable class is used to determine whether a product is displayed for normal users or staff only:

```
CONTENT_STATUS_DRAFT = 1
CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED = 2
CONTENT_STATUS_COMPLETE = 3
CONTENT_STATUS_INACTIVE = 4

CONTENT_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (CONTENT_STATUS_DRAFT, _("Draft")),
    (CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED, _("Online")),
    (CONTENT_STATUS_COMPLETE, _("Complete")),
    (CONTENT_STATUS_INACTIVE, _("Inactive")),
)


class Displayable(Slugged, MetaData, TimeStamped):
"""
Abstract model that provides features of a visible page on the
website such as publishing fields. Basis of Mezzanine pages,
blog posts, and Cartridge products.
"""

status = models.IntegerField(_("Status"),
    choices=CONTENT_STATUS_CHOICES, default=CONTENT_STATUS_DRAFT,
    help_text=_("The General public can only view content that has ONLINE status."))
```

In trying to filter the results by Status however I can't seem to get it to work the way I expect. In my report view I'll add something like this:

```
product_variations = ProductVariation.objects.filter('product__status' == 'CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED')
```

but it just gives me an error that "'bool' object is not iterable". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write:

```
ProductVariation.objects.filter('product__status' == 'CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED')
```

The expression `'product__status' == 'CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED'` becomes a boolean.

Right syntax is:

```
ProductVariation.objects.filter(product__status = 'CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED')
```

Comment: That is exactly right! When I access it correctly it works, well it's looking at the assigned integer field so once I changed it to (product__status = '2') it filters correctly. Thank you!